# What is the smallest duration that can be measured using micros()?

Tags: timers, arduino-micro, time

What is the least value of time that I could measure(count) using `micros()`?

Comment: What's unclear about [the official docs](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/micros/)?

Comment: Which board? I know you added the `arduino-micro` tag but I suspect you didn't add that because you're using an Arduino Micro board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the least value of time that I could measure(count) using micro() in Arduino board?

The answer is 64 clock cycles or 4 us @ 16 MHz. Please see the Arduino AVR core[1] for more details.

Cheers!

Ref. [1] https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L25

Comment: is there is any other way to count in nano seconds or 0.05 micro seconds?

Comment: @krishnamoorthijayakumar yes, by using a Timer and setting the prescaling to 1 (no prescaling). This will give a counter with 62.5 ns per tick @ 16 MHz.

Comment: Please accept and mark the question as answered!